# how to allow null?

Tags: sql, vb.net, project

> [column "uid" does not allow null error]

the above error has occurred while im trying to save my file in my project where i am using vb.net as front end and sql server mgmt studio as back end

Comment: Can you please show how you are adding `uid` in code ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Post your sql query here so that we can understand where is the error !

Comment: Just to clarify terms, management studio is the SQL Server client software you run to connect to the database, it's not your backend. You're then running SQL Server.

Comment: You should make sure that the value is not null. There will be a reason for null being disallowed.

Comment: Although I suspect there might be a whole lot more going on here that we aren't being made privy to.  The allow null is a property of the column in the database table design.  Guessing though, the column named uid what you may be looking for is the Identity setting to populate it with an autoInc id?

Answer (score 0):

Probably UID is primary key and it is by default not allow Nulls.